# How to force browsers to always cache static content

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache, static-content

I have an html file served from `file://` scheme and I want static bootstrap/jquery from CDN to be always cached. I.e. once they're downloaded first time I want browsers never ever perform network requests until I clear cache.

```
<head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Is there a way to achieve the behavior? Maybe by specifying some attributes in the code or a browser setting (Chrome, FF). I do not want to keep the content next to my html.

Answer (score 2):

Content loaded via `file://` is not delivered via HTTP. The Cache mechanism is part of HTTP, so you'll need to use a local server, such as node.js, if you want a cache to work.

Comment: I do not understand how transport protocol affects agent caching. Can you please elaborate? Does that mean that content delivered via protocols other than http(s) is never cached?

Comment: If you're loading a local files you are not using ANY transport protocol, you're just loading a file into the browser. It is the trasnport protocol itself that provides the cache mechanism. The browser asks the server "has x.html changed from the version I have?" If the server says "304" that means "NO, use your local cached copy". In your situation THERE IS NO SERVER to talk to. The cache mechanism, that is part of HTTP, is not used, so the browser cannot cache your local file. Therefore it treats it like a new copy, every time.

Comment: I don't care if browsers cache my local files but I do for resources referenced inside using http(s) protocol.

Comment: As long at the main page is not delivered via HTTP, none of the attached resources will be cache-managed. You're probably better off installing node.js and serving up your own local file via HTTP.